# Strikethrough not working in CoreText on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, core-text, strikethrough

Strikethrough is not being displayed, but underline does. The code is as below, its fairly straight forward. When I comment out the underline the text is displayed without a strikethrough, when I comment out the strikethrough and display the underline it works fine. I've tried everything — I must be missing something obvious, the docs say strikeout should work.

I'm running macOS 10.13.6 and Xcode 10.1.

```
import AppKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class CustomView: NSView {
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        let attrString = NSAttributedString(
            string: "Hello",
            attributes: [
                //NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.thick.rawValue,
                NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.thick.rawValue
            ]
        )
        let line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(attrString)

        // Set text position and draw the line into the graphics context.
        let context = (NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext)!
        context.translateBy(x: 10, y: 10)
        CTLineDraw(line, context)
    }
}

let customView = CustomView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = customView
```

**Playground settings**. To run this in a Xcode Playground just be sure to change the platform to macOS in the inspector settings (all new playgrounds are set to iOS by default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CoreText** does *not* have native support for the *strikethrough* typographic text decoration (but supports *underlines* just fine as you noted in your question). The full list of string attributes supported by CoreText is [described here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/core_text_string_attributes/string_attribute_name_constants).

This old, [Objective-C based blog post](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/) provides the necessary details to implement strikethrough manually using CoreText APIs. Unfortunately, not a quick fix at all.

---

The higher-level **TextKit** framework *does* provide strikethrough support though. To quickly see that working just replace this line in your original code:

```
CTLineDraw(line, context)
```

with this instead:

```
attrString.draw(at: .zero)
```

And, by the way, that somehow helps validate that there was nothing wrong with your original `NSAttributedString` to begin with ;)

Of course, depending on how much your code relies on CoreText, switching over to TextKit might be a non-trivial  task, so you need to keep that in mind as well.

Comment: Just an FYI for anyone looking how to do this in 2022: YES, you can cast a CFAttributeString to a NSAttributeString and set NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName -- and this WORKS -- but ONLY on MacOS 10.12 (Monterey).  When tested on 10.15 (Catalina) and 10.11 (Big Sur), no strikethrough was drawn.